# Installing php5.6-redis on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: php, redis, devops, ubuntu-16.04, phpredis

We are upgrading from ubuntu 14 to ubuntu 16, but are encountering problems installing php-redis. We're trying to get php-redis for php 5.6 but php-redis for php8.0 is being installed instead. When specifying the version e.g.

```
sudo apt-get install php5.6-redis
```

we get the following error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package php5.6-redis
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'php5.6-redis'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php5.6-redis'
```

we looked into [https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php/](https://launchpad.net/%7Eondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php/) but it seems this would only work for ubuntu 18+

any help is much appreciated on how we can install php-redis for php 5.6 on ubuntu 16

Comment: Why should they provide it for such a massively outdated PHP version, that has not even received any security fixes for ages? https://www.php.net/supported-versions.php

Comment: @CBroe is it not possible then? We're working on a codebase where things haven't been updated in a long time, trying to incrementally upgrade things to avoid breaking all things and php5.6 is hardcoded into quite a few places so if we could get it working on ubuntu 16 with 5.6 before upgrading php then I can die happy

Answer (score 0):

if you dont install the Redis itself on your ubuntu then you need to install it first by this command:

```
sudo apt-get install redis-server
```

after enabling it:

```
sudo systemctl enable redis-server.service
```

install the php extenstion:

```
sudo apt-get install php5.6-redis
```

Comment: Hey AliHpanahi,

Thanks for taking the time to write a solution, I'm afraid this didn't work. we get the same error of:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package php5.6-redis
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'php5.6-redis'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php5.6-redis'
```

it feels almost like there's no version of php-redis for php5.6 on ubuntu 16, but that can't be the case can it?

Answer (score 0):

If you installed Redis you can continue with this:

First you need to add repository:

```
sudo apt-add-repository -y ppa:ondrej/php
```

Then update APT:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Finally, install **php-redis** from apt:

```
sudo apt-get install php-redis
```

Comment: Ondrej's repo doesn't build `php5.6-redis` for Xenial.